# What are the differences and similarities between Magento plugin vs extension vs module?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8, magento-2.1

Please explain the differences and similarities amongst them with use cases

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182554/differences-between-an-extension-and-a-module

Comment: Personally I don't think that answer is correct. There is no difference. Different names for the same thing. TBH, not even sure (after all these years) which is the more 'official' term.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my kinda personal ways of seeing those terms:

### Module

**A module is a set of code files that add a new feature / improvement / bug fix to the core Magento code.** This is usually how I call the code I develop for a client to extend the original store.

### Extension

**An extension (again this is very personal) is a module provided by a vendor.** To me, the code you can download/install from Magento Connect, Magento Marketplace or directly via a vendor website is an extension.

### Plugin

Here comes the fun. **Before Magento 2, people tend to use this term to call modules/extensions simply because some CMS (such as WordPress, Drupal, Joomla) use this term to describe an extension / addon.**

However, there never was anything officially called plugins with Magento 1. **It's totally different with Magento 2 as this new version introduces a new concept called plugins and it must not be confused with extensions or module.** You can find out more about Magento 2 plugins on the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Those terms can have other technical meanings, but in the context of 'ways to refer to a package of third-party functionality': All three terms are synonymous and are often used interchangeably. They all mean a bunch of code you can install to enhance Magento in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the original term from magento.com, and that's extension. Plugins (interceptors) are a different thing in Magento 2.

In code, we reference it as a module, but module means strictly the php and xml code, might not contain the required template files. Once packaged to be uploaded to Magento Connect, including all files and templates, it's an extension.

Every time I hear "Magento Plugin" I imagine this scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Rze0XkDUqQ